# Tridion: Not able to copy paste the items in lower environment

Tags: content-management-system, tridion, tridion-content-manager

I'm not able to copy, paste the tridion items however its working fine in Production
CMS.
**Error Message: webui/models/tcm54/services/general.svc/copypasteitem failed to execute.
Status(500): Internal server error**

Can anyone please help on this?

I tried copy and paste paste the items within publication, its giving error message.

Comment: What version of Tridion is this? Are you able to copy and paste in the parent folder? Are you able to create the same type of item(s) in the child/target folder?

Comment: I'm using Tridion Sites 9.5 version. I am not able to copy/paste any items in Dev environment, but copy/paste is working fine in Production environment(its also 9.5 version).

Comment: Are you trying to cut/paste multiple items at once, or one at a time?

Comment: I'm getting the error, while copy/paste single item at a time.

Comment: to confirm... (1) you can manually create a component of the type you are trying to copy/paste - in the same folder? (2) there are no event system triggers or custom code running in the DEV env? (3) what "items" have you tried with... pages, components, templates, folders etc. (4) you are able to edit and save an item of the type you're attempting to copy?